# Importing an object to a class

Tags: python, namespaces

How do I import an object into the class's namespace and make it available for every function? Say I have a singleton object called `terrain` in `terrain.py` and I want all the creatures in a game to know something about the map.

In `creatures.py`:

```
class Creature:
    '''
    Basic class for mobile active things like player and monsters
    '''
    from terrain import terrain

    # ... some more code ...

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        '''
        move creature by dx and|or dy
        '''
        if terrain.item(self.x+dx, self.y+dy).passable==True:
            self.x+=dx
            self.y+=dy
```

Now `terrain` is not defined within `move` and throws `NameError`. Of course, it could've been:

```
def move(self, dx, dy):
    '''
    move creature by dx and|or dy
    '''
    from terrain import terrain
    self.x+=dx
    self.y+=dy
```

It works, but that way I have to import it in every single function. That's kind of ugly, so what's the correct way?

Comment: All imports should be *at the top of the script*, not inside classes/functions. See [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would be better if all your imports are at the top of your script, but if you want to do like this so much...

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        from Smith import John
        self.imp=John
    def run(self, args):
        self.imp.dosmth()
```